# CardView does not scale Images

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am using a Cardview which has an ImageView for a RecyclerView in Android. Unfortunately the CardView does not scale the images meaning that small images lead to smaller Items in the RecyclerView. Here you have a screenshot for which I used two different ImageResources (one big and one small):
[image]

Here is the XML code of the CardView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:contentPadding="0dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:contentPaddingBottom="0dp"
    app:contentPaddingLeft="7dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>




        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I tried using "wrap_content" for the attributes of the ImageView (and the LinearLayout) and I tried including the attribute "android:scaleType="fitXY" but it did not help and did not seem to have any effect.

Would someone mind helping me on that? I'd appreciate every comment and would be quite thankful for your help.

Comment: make the `CardView` width `match_parent`

Answer (score 0):

you need to give fix height to any view like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:contentPadding="0dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:contentPaddingBottom="0dp"
    app:contentPaddingLeft="7dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>




        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thanks umar for your answer. Basically I have to use "match_Parent" and not "wrap_content"